# не работает процедура для поиска значений что не повторяются

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть процедура:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE UniqueVal AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ColumnName varchar(50)

        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name='UniqueCount' AND xtype='U')
        CREATE TABLE UniqueCount (
            Name NVARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
            UniqueAmount Int Not null
            )
TRUNCATE TABLE UniqueCount;
DECLARE @Count int

DECLARE MY_CURSOR CURSOR 
LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
FOR 
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM footballlab.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Players'
OPEN MY_CURSOR
FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @ColumnName
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN 
            SELECT @Count = COUNT(DISTINCT @ColumnName)
            From Players
            INSERT INTO UniqueCount(Name,UniqueAmount)
            VALUES(@ColumnName, @Count);
            FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @ColumnName
        END
CLOSE MY_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE MY_CURSOR
END;
```

Я создаю таблицу, курсор. В курсоре я "прохожусь" по колонкам таблицы и записываю количество уникальных значений в кажой колонке.
Не работает строка SELECT `@Count = COUNT(DISTINCT @ColumnName)` - результат всегда "1" в таблице UniqueCount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Она работает, просто не так как вы ожидаете.
А вот что вам действительно нужно:

```
-- Заполним @Count

DECLARE @SQL_Script nvarchar(max)

SELECT @SQL_Script = 'SELECT @Count = COUNT (DISTINCT '+@ColumnName+') FROM [Players]'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL_Script, N'@Count int out', @Count out

SELECT @Count
```